# Combine matrices row by row

Tags: r, matrix, cbind, rowwise

I have two matrices of arbitrary sizes, e.g. matrix 1 (n * m) and matrix 2 (k * l). Is there a (convenient) way in R to `cbind` them row-by-row, to form a (n * k) * (m + l) matrix where each row of matrix 1 has a chance to be `cbind`ed to each row of matrix 2? It is a complete row-by-row combination so the order does not matter.

For example, is there a function `f` such that:
[please click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YWsr.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please include example data that is copy/pasteable, not just a picture.

```
m1 = matrix(1:6, ncol = 2)
m2 = matrix(7:12, ncol = 3)

combos = expand.grid(1:nrow(m1), 1:nrow(m2))
cbind(m1[combos$Var1, ], m2[combos$Var2, ])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    4    7    9   11
# [2,]    2    5    7    9   11
# [3,]    3    6    7    9   11
# [4,]    1    4    8   10   12
# [5,]    2    5    8   10   12
# [6,]    3    6    8   10   12
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better solution, but this works for smaller size problems:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,2,3,4), nrow = 3)
B <- matrix(c(5,6,6,7,7,8), nrow = 2)

temp <- lapply(1:nrow(A), function(x){
  C = apply(B, 1, function(y){
    c(A[x,],y)
  })
  return(t(C))
})

output <- do.call(rbind, temp)
```

Comment: Thank you! Using apply and lapply works well! I was just wondering there could be some function realizing this...

Comment: @KenChen if you don't have a name for this (I certainly don't), it's doubtful there is a function for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
cbind(A[rep(1:(x<-nrow(A)),each=y<-nrow(B)),],B[rep(1:y,x),])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    5    6    7
[2,]    1    2    6    7    8
[3,]    2    3    5    6    7
[4,]    2    3    6    7    8
[5,]    3    4    5    6    7
[6,]    3    4    6    7    8
```

## Break down:

```
  x=nrow(A)
  y=nrow(B)
  cbind(A[rep(1:x,each=y),],B[rep(1:y,x),])
```

Comment: Nice method, though putting it allononelinewithnospaces really just makes it difficult to read and understand.

Comment: I get what you mean